# Pylibnet installation error ubuntu 14

Tags: python, ubuntu, libnet

I've been looking in the internet for a solution of this issue when i try to install pylibnet , i would like to know if you guys were be able to install pylibnet succesfully and how.

Thanks

```
root@root:/home/core2# pip install ./pylibnet-3.0-beta-rc1.tar.gz
Unpacking ./pylibnet-3.0-beta-rc1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-LSMFJM-build/setup.py) egg_info for package from file:///home/core/pylibnet-3.0-beta-rc1.tar.gz
    Searching for libnet...
    Could not locate the static library "libnet.a"
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Searching for libnet...

Could not locate the static library "libnet.a"

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 255 in /tmp/pip-LSMFJM-build
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try runnning

```
$ find / | grep libnet.a
```

or

```
$ locate libnet.a
```

and if it is found somewhere then move it to /usr/lib/libnet.a because this is where pip looks for it when it trys to install pylibnet e.g.

```
$ sudo cp /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnet.a /usr/lib/libnet.a
```

this worked for me :-)